# FF reload page without cache values

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I'm trying to reload a page in angular js.

I'm using window.location.reload and it works with Chrome but in Chrome I keep getting old parameters in the url. That is one parameter old.

How to fix this in FF

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload);
```

I hope this helps! I had the same sort of problem quite a while ago and this seemed to fix it. Unfortunately, I don't have a great technical explanation as to why it did work.

edit: Actually you should probably inject the `$window` and `$timeout` service into your controller and use that!

It should probably look like:

```
$timeout($window.location.reload);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using currently.